# Style issues with fullcalendar 2

Tags: jquery-ui, fullcalendar

I have just upgraded to fullcalendar 2 and am now facing some styling issues that I can't seem to rectify. The calendar appears on http://horntonprimaryschool.co.uk/calendar/ and is using a jQuery UI theme.

When events are present it causes the border to be missing on the td's for that week, the current day background is also cut off if no event exists on that day

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer as I'm not sure what the exact css conflict is but the problem is related to foundation.css conflicting with fullcalendar css. I have reverted back to fullcalendar v1.5.4  which works.